# I am trying to make a schema for an array of objects and am not sure how to do this new to backend

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mern

I am trying to create a schema for an array of objects

Im just trying to make sure what i am doing so far is correct.

```
const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    cart: [{
        colorC: String,
        sizeC: String,
        date: Date,
        title: String,
        transactionID: Number,
        count: Number,
        lang: []
    }]
});
```

This is how the array looks when i console.log it.

```
[{…}]
0:
category: "Mens Fashion"
colorC: null
count: 1
date: "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
fabric: "100% Cotton"
id: 1
img: "img/product-1.png"
img2: "img/product-1-1.png"
img3: "img/product-1-2.png"
img4: "img/product-1-3.png"
inCart: true
info: " COMME DES GARCONS PLAY BASIC LOGO TEE"
lang: (3) ["en-US", "en", "pt"]
luxury: "All Luxury items are inspected to verify authenticity"
price: 200
size1: "Small"
size2: "Medium"
size3: "Large"
size4: "Extra Large"
sizeC: "Small"
title: "COMME DES GARCONS TEE"
total: 200
transactionID: 1564380487732
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do a collection of carts, and the carts has many products, you could do something like this:

#### A product schema:

```
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        colorC: String,
        sizeC: String,
        date: Date,
        title: String,
        transactionID: Number,
        count: Number,
        lang: []
});
```

And then a collection of carts with an array of products

```
const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        products: [ProductSchema]
});

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

Comment: Okay so would I have to import the product Schema into the cart Schema or can I do it I. The same file

Comment: all in the same file

Comment: Are you there i have one last question

Comment: Here is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300657/i-am-trying-to-create-a-new-cart-schema-with-a-request