# I am trying to create a new Cart schema with a request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mern

My Data is not being saved correctly

This is my SChema

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  colorC: String,
  sizeC: String,
  date: Date,
  title: String,
  transactionID: Number,
  count: Number
});

const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  products: [ProductSchema]
});

const Cart = mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);

module.exports = {
  cartModel: mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema),
  productModel: mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
};
```

this is my post request

```
const express = require('express');
const Cart = require('../models/Cart');
const models = require('../models/Cart');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count } = req.body;
  try {
    const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
      products: [
        {
          title,
          colorC,
          sizeC,
          count,
          date,
          transactionID
        }
      ]
    });

    const purchase = await newPurchase.save();

    res.json(purchase);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i send the data as an array containing two objects none of the data shows up for instance this is supposed to show the object i input.
When i send this the server does not save any products in the array.

This is what i am sending to the server

```
[{

"colorC": null,
"count": 1,
"date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
"sizeC": "Small",
"title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
"transactionID": 1564380487732

},{

"colorC": null,
"count": 1,
"date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
"sizeC": "Small",
"title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
"transactionID": 1564380487732

}]
```

This is the data saved in the Database

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5d42ab9f4ec81021f0136e95"},
    "products":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d42ab9f4ec81021f0136e94"}}]
    ,"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
    }
```

I am expecting the data to look like this

```
{
    "_id": "5d439bc758a1f004b876bac3",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5d439bc758a1f004b876bac4",
            "title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
            "colorC": null,
            "sizeC": "Small",
            "count": 1,
            "date": "2019-07-29T06:08:07.000Z",
            "transactionID": 1564380487732
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to restructure this file

```
 const express = require("express");
    const models = require("../models/Cart");
    const router = express.Router();

    router.post("/", (req, res) => {
      const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
        products: req.body.map(element => {
          const { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count } = element;
          return { colorC, sizeC, date, title, transactionID, count };
        })
      });

      newPurchase
        .save()
        .then(purchase => res.json(purchase))
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err.message);
          res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### mongoose schema does not have constructor

```
new models.ProductSchema({ ...data })
```

will give you an error.

#### to do so you have to export models of the schema

```
module.exports =  { 
    cartModel: mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema), 
    productModel: mongoose.model('Cart', ProductSchema),
}
```

now you can use models constructor to achieve what you want

```
const newProduct = new models.cartModel({
      colorC,
      sizeC,
      date,
      title,
      transactionID,
      count
    })
```

and then you can use your product to store into wherever you want

```
 const newPurchase = new models.CartSchema({
      products: [newProduct.toJSON()]
    });
```

and yes you have to save both.

```
newProduct.save();
newPurchase.save();
```

Comment: Okay i updated the question to my current code. It works but only when i send a single object. when i send an array with nested objects it doesnt work My data is structured in this way

Comment: ``const purchase = await newPurchase.save() + products;``
What do you mean by this ?

Comment: event better just give an example of response you want and from where ?

Comment: It is a typo in my code now I am just  calling purchase = newPurchase I’m in bed now I will update in the morning.

Comment: i don't understand why you are concating models.
`purchase =  newPurchase + products;`

if you want purchase info just do `res.json(newPurchase.toJSON());`

Comment: I was just debugging trying to get the correct data to show up in my database lol

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the

```
productModel: mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

You can just just save the full cart json:

```
const newPurchase = new models.cartModel({
    products:[{ 
        "colorC": null,
        "count": 1,
        "date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
        "sizeC": "Small",
        "title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
        "transactionID": 1564380487732
    },{
        "colorC": null,
        "count": 1,
        "date": "Mon Jul 29 2019 02:08:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)",
        "sizeC": "Small",
        "title": "COMME DES GARCONS TEE",
        "transactionID": 1564380487732
    }]
});

await newPurchase.save()
```

(obviously you have to take the values dynamically from the request body)

Comment: Okay I see. But what is I have more than two objects will this still work?

Comment: And should I change my Schema?

Comment: yes, you can add many products to the array, with the same schema. The ProductModel is not needed.

Comment: don't forget to remove the:
await newProduct.save(); and all related with newProduct

Comment: okay i will try this and let you know how it goes thank you so much

Comment: So i just sent the request with two objects and the data i still returning withoutt he products in the array